# Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'

Tags: android, gradle

I made a project on Windows, and when trying to open and build it using Ubuntu I get the following error. Can anyone help me sort it out? I've seen posts saying the changing 0.5.+ to 0.5.6, and that didn't help.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/media/Data/Android/SivLtdProject/FitnessUnlimited/build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':FitnessUnlimited'.
Cause: org/gradle/internal/reflect/Instantiator
Cause: org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

If you need anything else posting, just let me know.

After a bit of messing around I get the error NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/reflect/Instantiator

I installed gradle through apt-get, is there anything else I need to do to get it to build?

Comment: As @user852671 wrote run build with `--stacktrace` argument and paste the result. You can also paste your build and wrote which line is 9th.

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest gradle distribution (`1.8`) taken from gradle.org not from apt-get and with the latest Android gradle plugin: `0.6.+` or `0.6.1`

Additionally use `--stacktrace` option to get more detailed info about the issue.

Comment: I've downloaded gradle from gradle.org and (hopefully) got it installed okay (running gradle -version from terminal outputs the correct info), but when I try and build my project I still get the 1.7 error. Where do I tell it to use gradle 1.8 instead of 1.7?